# simple javascript (js) for onclick button is not working

Tags: javascript

```
 <html>
       <body>
         <script type="text/javascript">
        function changeText2(){
         var userInput = document.getElementById('userinp').value;
         document.getElementById('hii').innerhtml=userInput;
          }
           </script>

            <p>My name is <b id='hii'>yogesh</b> </p>
       <input type='text' id='userinp' value="enter text"/>
          <input type='button' onclick='changeText2()' value="changeme!!"/>


                                    </body>
                                 </html>
```

this is not working on click event.Same code i have copied other code  from the link as http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascript-innerHTML.php which as same as above is working can anyone help me.......

Comment: you can view similiar code on link i have given..I have done few editing in my code as shown here

Comment: Put your script before closing of body and use `innerHTML` instead of `innerhtml`

Comment: `.innerHTML !== .innerhtml`

Comment: Looks like [your code works well](http://jsfiddle.net/o66nrovq/) ; ). Maybe you should explain, what exactly means "not working" .

Comment: @BhojendraNepal No need to move the script, just spell innerHTML correctly